# How can i make a grid column cell to read only in Dev-Express?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I need to make a Grid Cell to be read only If my condition is false. In devexpress gridControl.

Comment: NOte: Only Dev-express Knowing people to be answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and change condition as per requirement

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e) {
    if (ASPxGridView1.IsNewRowEditing) return;
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "UnitPrice")
             if (ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(....) == ....)
                   e.Editor.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks , I had Changed the answer with my own way in WPF        private void tblView_ShowingEditor(object sender, ShowingEditorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row != null)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "ColumnName")
        {
           e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}